# How to scale the rotation of a quaternion

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am trying to do the equivalent of multiplying the velocity by the time between frames.  I would imagine that doing this for quaternions would be done by raising them to a power.  I have code to rotate an object based on my mouse movements.  It has a main loop running at one frame rate and a physics loop running at a fixed frame rate.  Here is the relevant part of the main loop:

```
glfwPollEvents();
Input::update();
window.clear(0,0,0,1);

rigidBody.angularVelocity *= glm::angleAxis(0.001f * Input::deltaMouse().x, glm::vec3(0,1,0));
rigidBody.angularVelocity *= glm::angleAxis(0.001f * Input::deltaMouse().y, glm::vec3(1,0,0));

if(Input::getKey(Input::KEY_A))
{
    rigidBody.velocity -= float(Time::getDelta()) * glm::vec3(1,0,0);
}
if(Input::getKey(Input::KEY_D))
{
    rigidBody.velocity += float(Time::getDelta()) * glm::vec3(1,0,0);
}
if(Input::getKey(Input::KEY_W))
{
    rigidBody.velocity -= float(Time::getDelta()) * glm::vec3(0,0,1);
}
if(Input::getKey(Input::KEY_S))
{
    rigidBody.velocity += float(Time::getDelta()) * glm::vec3(0,0,1);
}
if(Input::getKey(Input::KEY_LCONTROL))
{
    rigidBody.velocity -= float(Time::getDelta()) * glm::vec3(0,1,0);
}
if(Input::getKey(Input::KEY_LSHIFT))
{
    rigidBody.velocity += float(Time::getDelta()) * glm::vec3(0,1,0);
}
```

Here is the relevant part of the physics loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < *numRigidBodies; i++)
{
    rigidBodies[i].transform->getPos() += rigidBodies[i].velocity;
    rigidBodies[i].transform->getRot() *= rigidBodies[i].angularVelocity;
}
rigidBodies[0].angularVelocity = glm::quat();
rigidBodies[0].velocity = glm::vec3();
```

This works fine, but when I try raising angular velocity to a power with glm::pow, the object rotates randomly and does not follow my mouse.  I realize I could do this with a line of code like

```
rigidBodies[i].transform->getRot() *= glm::angleAxis((float)Time::getFixedDelta() * glm::angle(rigidBodies[i].angularVelocity), glm::axis(rigidBodies[i].angularVelocity));
```

but this seems needlessly complicated for the task.  What is causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

Comment: There isn't a unique square root of a quaternion, or indeed of a rotation.  A rotation of 10 degrees could be two rotations of 5 degrees, or two rotations of 185 degrees.  Both, when composed, produce a rotation of 10 degrees.  In general, the nth root of a rotation of k degrees is the set x 360/n + k/n for x from 0 to n-1.  I don't know what your library does, I'm just pointing out that the math is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly how to do it with the API you're using, but basically, you would use Quaternion::Slerp(). Slerp means "spherical linear interpolation".

Something like this(pseudocode) should work:

```
auto& rot = rigidBodies[i].transform->getRot();

auto goal = rigidBodies[i].angularVelocity * rot;
rot = rot.slerp(rot, goal, Time::deltaTime);
```

**Edit:**
I should note that this is not how I would approach this problem. I would just store the rotation around the X and Y axis as scalars and construct a new quaternion from them each frame.

Please excuse the sloppy pseudo code:

```
// previous x and y positions, could probably be set in MouseDown event
float lastX = ...; 
float lastY = ...;

float xRotation = 0;
float yRotation = 0;

float rotationSpeed = 1.0;

void OnMouseMove(float x, float y) {
    float dx = x - lastX;
    float dy = y - lastY;
    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;

    xRotation += dy * rotationSpeed * Time::deltaTime;
    yRotation += dx * rotationSpeed * Time::deltaTime;

    rigidBodies[i].transform->getRot() = eulerQuat(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
}
```

Comment: I apologize for the not saying what API i am using.  Time is a class I implemented, and so is transform.  I am using the GLM math library, and that is the important one for this.  I want to avoid x and y rotations because Euler Angles because this is supposed to work for all physics objects.

Comment: so use the first solution

Comment: That solution works up to a point, but when I get above a certain angular speed it becomes erratic as well

Comment: This is not actually solving the problem but rather trying to circumvent it. The "needlessly complicated" solution at the end of the original question is the proper solution.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out angular velocity is usually represented as a 3d vector where the direction is the axis and the magnitude is the angular speed. Replace this line of code:

```
rigidBodies[i].transform->getRot() *= rigidBodies[i].angularVelocity;
```

with this:

```
if(rigidBodies[i].angularVelocity != glm::vec3())
    rigidBodies[i].transform->getRot() *= glm::quat(rigidBodies[i].angularVelocity * float(Time::getFixedDelta()));
```

and the physics system works as expected.  The if check makes sure that angular speed is not 0.

Comment: It's incorrect to treat angle-axis values as euler angles even though they sometimes yield similar quaternions. The "needlessly complicated" solution at the end of the original question is the proper solution.